# If the first r columns of U are linearly independent, then so are the first r columns of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $U$ be a row echelon form of a square matrix $A$.
If the first $r$ columns of $U$ are linearly independent, then should the first $r$ columns of $A$ be linearly independent?

In my opinion, "Yes"
Let $\{v_1,v_2, … , v_r\}$ be the first $r$ columns of $U$.
Then clearly the set is a basis for the column space $C(U)$ and thus $\text{rank } U = r$. Since $R(U)=R(A)$ and $\dim R(A)=\dim C(A)$, we get $\dim C(A) = r$.
Since the row operations does not give an effect to columns, I think the linearly independence preserves. Therefore, the first $r$ columns of $A$ are also linearly independent.

Is my answer correct? If not, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

By construction of the row echelon form, there is an invertible matrix $S$, so that $U = SA$ or $S^{-1}U =A$.

It follows that the columns $a_i$ of $A$ satisfy $a_i = S^{-1}v_i$. Thus, if $v_1\dots v_r$ are linearly independent, then the vectors $a_1 \dots a_r$ are linearly independent as well.